# Repaint in AchartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine, repaint

I am new to android. I am using AChartEngine to plot the frequency spectrum from Accelerometer.

I understand that repaint(), refreshes the plot. I have an issue here.

When I do repaint, whole view i.e X-Axis, Y-Axis and The plot is getting repainted. I am looking for a function or a command which only refreshes the plot.

Also, When I repaint, it looks like the screen is flickering. I would like to make the repaint operation smooth.

Please help.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a version of the `repaint` method that will allow you redraw only a given part of the chart view:

```
repaint(left, top, right, bottom);
```